# What does the declared empty list as a passed value represent?

Tags: python

[image]

From my understanding, the inbound_nodes=[] passed to the **init** just declares an empty list. So even if I create a subclass of Node and in that subclass call this **init** function with no arguments passed, the __init__function would still work, as it declared an empty list itself.

Am I right?

The next question is, we can see that self.inbound_nodes = inbound_nodes.

Does it mean, that self.inbound_nodes is also an empty list but inside the Node superclass? If so, why can't I just declare self.outbound_nodes in the same way?

And the last question is, what does the last for loop does?

Comment: Python does not have variable declarations, you are *initializing* an empty list, using a list literal syntax, then *setting that as a default parameter*. You aren't *passing anything*, that is a *function definition*. Note, this is a source of common bugs, if you do not understand the way python default parameters work, see [this famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Also, `self.inbound_nodes = inbound_nodes` creates an instance variable `self.inbound_nodes` and assigns it to the *same object* as `inbound_nodes`. You should really just read a tutorial on OOP in Python. Also, please do not *post pictures of code!*. Code is text. Please post your code as formatted text *in the question itself*.

Comment: the inbound_nodes=[] argument is a default value, which means if the caller call the function with a list it is ok and if not it will pass an empty list

Comment: Another good read on [mutable default arguments and why you need to be careful to understand how they work in Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

Comment: It is preferable to post the actual code/data instead of an image of the code/data.

Comment: One nice thing about Python being an interpreted language is that you can have a quick and easy write-test-modify-test-... cycle.  You can play around with that class in the shell and probably get a good idea of the answers to all your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. When parameters are initialized at the function definition, they are only executed once. It will create an empty list and use that as a **default argument**. That means, all the objects which were initalized with the default parameters use the **same list**

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, inbound=[]):
        self.inbound = inbound

class SubNode(Node):
    pass

node = Node()
subnode = SubNode()

print node.inbound is subnode.inbound  # returns True
print id(node.inbound)  # 66058248
print id(subnode.inbound)  # 66058248
```

It's the same list object.
That's because function parameters are evaluated only once. If you wanted each object has its own empty list, you should define the init as follows

```
def __init__(self, inbound=None):
        self.inbound = inbound or []
```

Regarding the loop, I'm not sure what it is suppose to do.

Comment: So, for example, let's say that I have created a new sublcass called A:
`class A(Node)`

So in my subclass A, I wrote this code:

`class A(Node):
    def __init__(self):
         Node.___init___(self)`


Does it mean, that because I did not pass any values, by default, class A will get self.inbound = []?

Comment: You don't need to call `Node.__init__(self)` as it happens by default if you don't override it. And yes, it will have the same list object. Think about it that way, the function is evaluted once and a default list object is created. When the function is called (object creation) that list object is assigned unless another object is provided.

Comment: @AbylIkhsanov if you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting it. thanks